# Ezybox hot shoe bracket

Tags: flash, softbox, flash-bracket

I've recently purchased a Lastolite Ezybox softbox L2495 and looking for a speedlight bracket. They sell Lastolite Ezybox Hot Shoe Mark II bracket but it seems smaller than the attachment plate which comes with the softbox. What bracket should I buy?

[image: The Softbox itself]

[image: The Attachment plate]

Comment: "seems smaller"--have you just tried using the plate that came with the softbox? The fit _does_ have to be tight to keep the softbox from falling off.

Comment: The plate that comes with the softbox fits nicely. But the thing is, that plate is designed for studio strobes and not for speedlights. I wonder if there's a right bracket that fit this softbox

Answer (score 1):

The Lastolite Ezybox hot shoe bracket is what you want. I can only find a [kit](https://www.manfrotto.us/strobo-pro-kit-ezybox-hotshoe-mount) on the Lastolite site, but I see that [B&H](https://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/629320-REG/Lastolite_LL_LS2414_Ezybox_Hot_Shoe_Mark.html) has just the bracket.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[An Amazon review](https://www.amazon.com/review/R2PFKMNKBG7VB1/ref=ask_dp_lswr_rp_hza) mentions that the [Godox S-Type Bowens-mount bracket](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00N3OFC2Q) works well for the standard Ezybox softboxes.

> 5.0 out of 5 stars
>
> Also works great for Ezybox, February 2, 2016
>
> By mcas
>
> Verified Purchase
>
> This review is from: Godox S-type Bracket Bowens S Mount Holder for T+L Speed Ring Softbox Speedlite Softbox Beauty Dish Reflector Umbrella (Camera)
>
> I ended up returning this because I realized afterward that I needed the Elinchrom mount, but I wanted to mention that this bracket is cleverly designed... while the inner part is for Bowens mount, the outer edge of the circle is exactly the right size to allow for the standard rectangular / square Ezybox to attach to (though I don't think it would work with the octagonal Ezybox without the appropriate speedring added).